# iPad Application crashing on MP4 creation with array of images

Tags: ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am getting crash when i am going to create video with array of images when there is an array with length of more than 100 objects then it is giving memory warning and crashing. Anyone please help me how it could be handled. I am working on ARC project. Please see below code which i am using for MP4 Video.

```
 NSError *error;
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/video.mov"];
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,

                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:1024], AVVideoWidthKey,

                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:768], AVVideoHeightKey,

                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* videoStream = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];


AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput: videoStream sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
[videoWriter addInput:videoStream];
[videoWriter startWriting];

[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0,3.2)];


CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
int frameCount = 2;

for(int i=0;i<[imagesArray count];i++)
{
    @try{

    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] CGImage] andSize:CGSizeMake(1024,768)];
    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData){
        CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) 03.1);
        append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
        if(buffer)
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.02];

    }else
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
    //time ++;
    frameCount++;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception---writevideo%@",exception.description);
    }
}
if (buffer) {
    CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
}

[videoStream markAsFinished];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
               {
                   [videoWriter finishWriting];

               });





-(CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image andSize:(CGSize) size
  {
@try{
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width,size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge   CFDictionaryRef) options,&pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,1024,768),image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
return pxbuffer;
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception---pixelBufferFromCGImage%@",exception.description);
  }
 }
```

Thanks in advance. please let me know where i am wrong in this and how i can handle this to make it workable.

Comment: Please supply crash log, debug out and what you have tried to solve the memory issue.

Comment: It is not showing any crash log. It is a memory leak and only showing some time Receive memory leak. Please let me if i could find out the same.

Comment: Well in your `pixelBufferFromCGImage:andSize:` methods your are calling create on some objects but never releasing them.

Comment: I am using ARC project and it should be managed by ARC or not. Please advise how it could be manage. What can i do for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No CoreFoundation object are managed by ARC.

Comment: Okay, Could you please let me know which object need to release and and how this issue could be resolved.?